# como utilizar o last-child para o penúltimo também?

Tags: css, css3

Quero fazer uma seleção com o css para último e o penúltimo item.

Sei que posso utilizar o seletor `last-child` para o último, mas e o penúltimo? como faço?

Comment: Você quer só o penúltimo ou o último e o penúltimo?

Comment: Pergunta interessante, vai levar meu +1. Aguardo a resposta ao questionamento anterior

Comment: Relacionado: [O que significa "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/o-que-significa-o-n-nos-seletores-nth-child-ou-nth-last-child)

Comment: quero saber os dois para poder aprender mais, mas eu preciso utilizar o ultimo e o penultimo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se você está querendo capturar o último e o penúltimo elemento, utilize `nth-last-child(-n+2)`:

```css
ul.test li {
  padding:10px;
  background-color: pink;
  list-style:none;
}

ul.test li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li>primeiro</li>
  <li>segundo</li>
  <li>terceiro</li>
  <li>penúltimo</li>
  <li>último</li>
</ul>
```

Para capturar apenas o penúltimo use `nth-last-child(2)`:

```css
ul.test li {
  padding:10px;
  background-color: pink;
  list-style:none;
}

ul.test li:nth-last-child(2) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ul class="test">
  <li>primeiro</li>
  <li>segundo</li>
  <li>terceiro</li>
  <li>penúltimo</li>
  <li>último</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Acho que seu exemplo ficaria mais claro com alguma coisa nos primeiros itens (<li>primeiro</li> <li>segundo</li> ...)

Comment: @Marco editado, amigo. Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Acertou miseravi!