# O que significam o "n", números e sinais nos seletores "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"?

Tags: css3

Sempre usei o `n` combinado com o seletor `nth-child` ou `nth-last-child` no CSS, porém eu ainda não consegui entender direito o seu significado.

Por exemplo:

```css
p:nth-child(3n+0) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
<p>Teste</p>
```

Ou

```css
div p:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Teste</p>
  <p>Teste</p>
  <p>Teste</p>
  <p>Teste</p>
  <p>Teste</p>
  <p>Teste</p>
</div>
```

O que significa o `n` nos pseudo-seletores de posição no CSS?

O que o `n` representa nessa expressão?

O que significam os números e sinais que acompanham essa expressão com `n`, como `-n+2` ou `3n+0`?

Comment: Aqui explica bem por alto: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: @diegofm por isso mesmo decidi fazer a  pergunta. Tá muito "por alto". Alguns exemplos deixam o cara mais confuso do que esclarecidod :D

Answer (score 43, accepted):

"nth" pode ser "traduzido" como "enésimo". "Enésimo" justamente porque é "n", ou seja, qualquer número. Quando você diz 3n, significa "a cada três", "5n" a cada cinco, e assim por diante. O `+` e `-` em seguida indicam um ponto de partida opcional.

Em resumo, `5n+2` significa:

> "Atue a cada 5 ítens, começando do segundo"

`9n-1` pode ser visto assim:

> "Atue a cada 9 ítens, contando do -1"

(neste caso, você só vai ver o efeito no 8º ítem, pois o -1 só existe "matematicamente", mas não faz parte do que é exibido na tela).

Ou simplesmente `4n` (não precisa por `+` quando é zero), que quer dizer

> "Atue a cada 4 ítens".

## `odd` e `even`

Você tem os atalhos `odd` e `even`, que significam `impar` e `par`, respectivamente. Basicamente o `odd` equivale a `2n+1` e o `even` a `2n`.

## Exemplo do `n` (múltiplo):

Veja a diferença dos ítens com `n`:

```css
#a span:nth-child(2n) {background-color:red  }
#b span:nth-child(3n) {background-color:green}
#c span:nth-child(4n) {background-color:blue }
span {color:white;display:inline-block;padding:0 10px;background:#ccc}
```

```html
<div id="a"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> 2n</div><br>
<div id="b"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> 3n</div><br>
<div id="c"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> 4n</div><br>
```

- múltiplos de 2 em vermelho, no A;
- múltiplos de 3 em verde, no B;
- múltiplos de 4 em azul, no C.

## Exemplo do `+` e `-` (ponto de partida):

Para este exemplo, vamos usar múltiplos de 4 (`4n`) em todos os casos:

```css
#a span:nth-child(4n  ) {background-color:red  }
#b span:nth-child(4n+1) {background-color:green}
#c span:nth-child(4n-1) {background-color:blue }
span {color:white;display:inline-block;padding:0 10px;background:#ccc}
```

```html
<div id="a"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> 4n  </div><br>
<div id="b"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> 4n+1</div><br>
<div id="c"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> 4n-1</div><br>
```

- começando do zero, em vermelho, no A (na prática, se efetiva do 4º e seguintes);
- começando do 1º em verde, no B;
- começando do -1 em azul, no C (na prática, se efetiva no 3º e seguintes).

Note que o intervalo de todos é o mesmo, o deslocamento é que mudou. O `A` é o deslocamento original (omissão do `+`, equivale ao `+0` ou `-0`). Na coluna `B`, deslocamos a contagem "para a "frente", com `+1`, e na coluna `C` deslocamos a contagem "para trás" com `-1`.

Note que em qualquer caso, `4n+4` é quase a mesma coisa que `+0`, e `4n+16` também, afinal tanto `4` quanto `16` são múltiplos de 4. O que muda é onde se inicia a contagem (entenda melhor comparando com o `-n`)

Da mesma forma, `4n+1` e `4n-3` são quase a mesma coisa, pois a diferença entre `+1` e `-3` é 4 mesmo. O que muda é em qual elemento começa a contagem (como números negativos "não aparecem na tela", o efeito é o mesmo).

## Invertendo o sentido com `-n`

O `-n` talvez seja um pouquinho mais complicado de se entender. Basicamente ele conta do ponto de partida "para trás". Não confundir com o `nth-last-child`, que conta desde o último.

Assim, se você usar `-2n+7`, vai estar contando de 2 em 2, do sétimo ítem para "trás". Os ítens maiores que 7 não serão afetados.

```css
#a span:nth-child( 2n+7) {background-color:red  }
#b span:nth-child(-2n+7) {background-color:green}
#c span:nth-child( -n+7) {background-color:blue }
span {color:white;display:inline-block;padding:0 10px;background:#ccc}
```

```html
<div id="a"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> 2n+7</div><br>
<div id="b"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> -2n+7</div><br>
<div id="c"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <span>03</span> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> <span>13</span> -n+7</div><br>
```

## `nth-last-child`

A lógica do `nth-last-child` é a mesma, mas contando do último ítem para trás. Em princípio, é possível fazer quase tudo que o `nth-last-child` faz usando apenas o `nth-child`, mas se você tem uma aplicação dinâmica onde o número de ítens varia, melhor usar o seletor que seja adequado para cada caso, para não ter que ficar recalculando os índices. Se você também vai ter algum intervalo antes de começar a selecionar os ítens, ou no caso do `-n`, é importante ter os dois seletores para escolher qual é o mais adequado.

## `nth-of-type`

Temos ainda o `nth-of-type` que não foi mencionado na pergunta. Todos os seletores "enesimais" usam a mesma lógica. O `nth-of-type` é um facilitador, que considera o tipo do elemento, e não apenas sua posição (ele só conta quando o elemento for do tipo indicado).

```css
#a span:nth-child(2n+1)   {background-color:red  }
#b span:nth-of-type(2n+1) {background-color:green}
span,em {color:white;display:inline-block;padding:0 10px;background:#ccc}
```

```html
<div id="a"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <em>03</em> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> :nth-child(2n+1)</div><br>
<div id="b"><span>01</span> <span>02</span> <em>03</em> <span>04</span> <span>05</span> <span>06</span> <span>07</span> <span>08</span> <span>09</span> <span>10</span> <span>11</span> <span>12</span> :nth-of-type(2n+1)</div><br>
```

- usamos um `em` no lugar do `span` no ítem `03`
- o `:nth-child(2n+1)` não estilizou o `em`, mas o incluiu na contagem
- o `:nth-of-type(2n+1)` "pulou" o `em` da contagem, inclusive.

Comment: Esta explicação merecia estar em inglês na MDN.

Answer (score 8):

***A ideia dessa resposta é apenas complementar o que foi dito pelo @bacco, porém com mais alguns exemplos e casos de uso. Além de fazer alguns esclarecimentos de sobre outros pontos não abordados.***

Segundo a documentação oficial da W3C <kbd>n</kbd> pode ser um número inteiro (positivo, negativo ou 0).  E o índice do primeiro filho de um elemento é `1`.  *Logo  `:nth-child(0n + 0.1)` não é valido* Fonte: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo

A `Formula` de acordo com a W3C seria **(a*n*+b)**, de forma que `an` determina o tamanho do grupo e `b` o index, `ex: (3n+3) = ((3xn)+3)`.

```
:nth-child(5n)
```

Representa os elementos de número [5×1]=**5**, [5×2]**10**, [5×3]=**15**, etc.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
:nth-child(3n+4)
```

Representa os elementos de número [(3×0)+4]=**4**, [(3×1)+4]=**7**, [(3×2)+4]=**10**, [(3×3)+4]=**13**, etc.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
:nth-child(-n+3)
```

Representa de traz para frente os últimos três elementos. [=-0+3, -1+3, -2+3]

```
:nth-child(odd) ou :nth-child(2n+1)
```

Representa as linhas ímpares de uma tabela HTML: 1, 3, 5, etc.

```
:nth-child(even) ou :nth-child(2n)
```

Representa as linhas pares de uma tabela HTML: 2, 4, 6, etc.

```
nth-child(n)
```

Representa todos os elementos filhos

Para entender melhor veja as imagens abaixo com uma abordagem diferente:

**Blocos de 2 pegando o index 1**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Blocos de 3 pegando o index 2**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Fonte:* https://www.sitepoint.com/atoz-css-screencast-nth-child/

Se o valor de `b` for `negativo`, o elemento correspondente no grupo será o `bth` *index*, mas contado de trás para a frente do índice 1. Nesse caso, o elemento correspondente de um grupo não corresponderá mais a um elemento desse grupo, mas a um acima dele.

Usando `nth-last-child` vc pode aplicar as mesmas regras, só que dessa forma o index de contagem começa de traz para frente.

**Last-child** Blocos de 3, mas começando de traz para frente `321` **não** `123`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou ressaltar que usando `nth-child` vc pode ter os mesmos resultados, porém utilizando "regras" diferentes. Como pode ser visto abaixo, todas as regras resultam em estilizar apenas o terceiro elemento.

```css
.foo span:nth-child(0n+3) {
    background-color: blue;
}
.bar span:nth-child(+3) {
    background-color: blue;
}
.foobar span:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
}
span {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#f00
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
<div class="foobar">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
```

Outro caso de uso seria estilizar só de determinado elemento <kbd>n</kbd> para frente, por exemplo para dividir uma lista da metade para frente. **Ex:** em uma lista de 10 elementos vc usaria `n+6` para estilizar do sexto elemento até o final da lista.

```css
.foo span:nth-child(n+6) {
    background-color: blue;
}
span {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#f00
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
```

Outro caso de uso por exemplo é quando vc quer deixar de aplicar o estilo no *primeiro* e no *último* filho. Vc pode concatenar duas `pseudo-classes` para só estiliza o "miolo" e deixa o primeiro e último filho sem o estilo:

```css
.foo span:nth-child(n+2):nth-last-child(n+2) {
    background-color: blue;
}
span {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#f00
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
```

E caso vc quera ser ainda mais específico e *pegar os apenas os elementos de 4 a 8* vc pode concatenar dois `nth-child` para fazer um `range` onde vc só pega o que estiver entre o quarto e o oitavo filho. Veja como fica no exemplo abaixo:

```css
.foo span:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8) {
    background-color: blue;
}
span {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#f00
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
```

Mas calma, vc ainda pode ser mais específico! Por exemplo *eliminar o filho 6* desse range, para isso vc deve concatenar tudo com uma regra `not(:nth-child())` no final excluindo do `range` o filho indesejado, veja como fica no exemplo que segue:

```css
.foo span:nth-child(n+4):nth-child(-n+8):not(:nth-child(6)) {
    background-color: blue;
}
span {
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color:#f00
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
</div>
```

---

A formatação do estilo também deve ser feita com atenção visto que `espaços em branco` podem quebrar a sua regra:

Exemplos **válido** com espaços em branco

```
:nth-child( 3n + 1 )
:nth-child( +3n - 2 )
:nth-child( -n+ 6)
:nth-child( +6 )
```

Exemplos **inválido** com espaços em branco

```
:nth-child(3 n)
:nth-child(+ 2n)
:nth-child(+ 2)
```