# Erro ao usar nth-child() do CSS

Tags: html, css, front-end

```
.citacao-bio {
    background-color: #D9E5E3;
    border: 10px solid #C2CCCA;
    width: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.citacao-bio:nth-child(2){
    float: right;
}

<div class="citacao-bio">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pulvinar dictum est, eget suscipit eros luctus blandit. Aliquam sodales nibh purus, vel aliquam nulla pretium et. Nunc pharetra tortor quis dolor viverra malesuada.
</div>

<div class="citacao-bio">
 Integer bibendum est felis, sit amet tempor elit posuere tincidunt. Cras tempus pharetra velit sed aliquet. Vivamus blandit magna commodo facilisis accumsan. Sed vitae pretium augue.
</div>
```

Estou tentando colocar o segundo item à direita do conteúdo, porém sem sucesso, e não consigo encontrar o erro.

Comment: Poste o HTML para vermos...

Comment: são só duas divs com lorem

Comment: Aqui funcionou seu código. Não tem nada no meio dessas DIVS ?

Comment: @MuriloGambôa só com esse código funcionou perfeitamente. Se ele esta quebrando para para baixo pode ser devido a erro matemático, ex.: você tem um div pai com 250px e esta pondo duas filhas de 140px que somaria 280px. Gerando o erro de quebra.

Comment: mas eu só to dando o float, o tamanho está certo, mas ele não ta indo pro lado certo

Comment: Sugestão de leitura [O que significa o N nos seletores "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/70)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, depois de um tempo, havia esquecido aqui no stack, a sintaxe correta para o uso é

EX:

```
:nth-child(1n){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o [nth Tester](https://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/) do CSS Tricks. Vai te ajudar.

Uma boa para você cria Layouts também seria ultilizar o [Flexbox](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/flexbox/). Ele já possui uma boa compatibilidade com os navegadores mais modernos.

Comment: sobre o flexbox eu sei, só que eu to fazendo esse teste, porque colocarei essas divs como blockquotes no site, e precisam utilizar a classe, pois haverão outras divs. vou checar o tester :3

Comment: é, o tester não vai funcionar, pois eu to usando classes, e nele só podem li's e divs

Comment: Murilo, é a mesma lógica com `li` ou `class`. Posta teu HTML aí pra ficar mais fácil de entender.