# Como limitar o tamanho de uma div

Tags: html, css

Bom, eu não sei que titulo hei-de dar a pergunta, portanto se alguém desejar editar eu aceito.

Eu tenho o seguinte esquema:

http://151.80.152.6/home.php

Pretendo fazer com a div itemsatuais, tenha aquela largura limitada, mas que as divs, que estejam por dentro, ou seja as divs item, assim que chegam ao limite de divs, que cabem dentro da div desapareçam. Ou seja suponhemos que só cabem 10 divs, lá dentro e no código estão 14. Só aparecem 10.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Meu código:

HTML:

```
<div class="itemsatuais">
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.itemsatuais{
background-color:#263238;
width:95%;
display:flex;
justify-content:10px;
height:16%;
margin-top:8%;
margin-left:2.5%;
position:absolute;
}
.item{
width:100px;
border-style: solid;
margin-left:10px;


}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Você quer que os elementos dentro da "itemsatuais" além do limite definido nem sejam adicionados?

Comment: Você ja utilizou `overflow: hidden` em `.itemsatuais` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes acrescentar nos css:

```
.itemsatuais .item:nth-child(n+11) {
  display:none;
}
```

Basicamente estás a dizer que queres só os primeiros 10 `.item` visíveis

```css
.itemsatuais{
background-color:#263238;
width:95%;
display:flex;
justify-content:10px;
height:16%;
margin-top:8%;
margin-left:2.5%;
position:absolute;
}
.item{
width:100px;
border-style: solid;
margin-left:10px;
}

.itemsatuais .item:nth-child(n+11) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemsatuais">
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>
<div class="item">
</div>  
</div>
```

[Excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/o-que-significam-o-n-n%C3%BAmeros-e-sinais-nos-seletores-nth-child-ou-nth-last) sobre o pseudo-seletores de posição.