# Qual a diferença entre o :nth-child e o :nth-of-type?

Tags: css, seletores

Na maioria das vezes eu utilizo o *:nth-of-type* porém não entendi exatamente a diferença entre os dois, alguém consegue explicar?

Comment: Já respondida em [O que significam o "n", números e sinais nos seletores "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/o-que-significam-o-n-n%c3%bameros-e-sinais-nos-seletores-nth-child-ou-nth-last)

Comment: @Bacco essa não seria uma pergunta mais especifica?

Comment: A pergunta é específica, mas a resposta dada lá responde com demonstração e tudo. Lembre-se que fechamento não tira a pergunta do site e nem é demérito, tampouco sinal de problema. A pergunta continua válida e serve de índice para a outra postagem.

Comment: E o titulo da sua pergunta ajudará outros usuários a encontrarem a solução, será semelhante a mesclar :) ... a sua continua vinculada :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

o `:nth-child()` irá considerar todos elementos filhos **"diretos"** no valor/calculo passado entre os parenteses, então por exemplo um "efeito zebra":

```css
div, p {
    background: #cfcfcf;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

p:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>

    <div>foo</div>

    <p>d</p>
    <p>e</p>
    <p>f</p>
</section>

<hr>

<section>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>

    <div>foo</div>

    <p>d</p>
    <p>e</p>
    <p>f</p>
</section>
```

Veja que mesmo `<div>foo</div>` sendo diferente de `<p>` ainda sim o efeito zebra continua considerando ele.

Agora o efeito é diferente com `:nth-of-type`, irá notar que ele irá desconsiderar o `<div>foo</div>`, pois somente os do tipo definido antes do `:` serão considerados, resultado:

```css
div, p {
    background: #cfcfcf;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

p:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>

    <div>foo</div>

    <p>d</p>
    <p>e</p>
    <p>f</p>
</section>

<hr>

<section>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>b</p>
    <p>c</p>

    <div>foo</div>

    <p>d</p>
    <p>e</p>
    <p>f</p>
</section>
```

---

Veja a diferença de ambas na imagem:

[image: nth-child vs nth-of-type]

Na primeira (com `nth-child`) o `<p>d</p>` ficou com o fundo vermelho, isto porque o elemento anterior `<div>foo</div>` apesar de não ser afetado pelo CSS ele é considerado no "calculo" `2n+1` (ou qualquer que seja passado entre os parenteses).

Já no segundo (com `nth-of-type`), o `<p>d</p>` continuou cinza e tudo que veio após o `<div>foo</div>` passou a ter outras cores, isso porque o `<div>foo</div>` não é considerado, pois o seletor `nth-of-type` especifica que só podem ser do mesmo tipo para que o calculo considere.

Answer (score 0):

> O seletor: nth-child, significa selecionar um elemento se:

`É um elemento de parágrafo.`

`É o segundo filho de um pai`

> O seletor:nth-of-type, significa selecionar um elemento se:

`Selecione o segundo parágrafo filho de um pai`

```css
p:nth-child(2) { color: blue; }

p:nth-of-type(2) { color: red; }
```

```html
<section>
   <p>Little</p>
   <span>Piggy</span>   
   <p>teste</p>
</section>
```

> O **nth-of-type** tem menos condições de avaliação. [fonte](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)