# Como posso usar os pseudo elementos css

Tags: css, css3, css-font-face, pseudo-elementos

Seguindo um tutorial de css3, aprendi a colocar icone dentro dos inputs.

O dev que estava ensinando usou um exemplo de 2 inputs para colocar 2 icones 1 em cada input.

No caso utilizou os seguintes pseudo elementos: 
.form-group::before
.form-group:last-of-type::before

Mas na minha situação tenho 3 inputs qual pseudo devo usar para colocar um icone no terceiro imput ?

Comment: Ronaldo que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone `✔` abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da minha resposta :) assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc deve usar o pseudo classe `:nth-of-type(n)` onde "n" é o número da ordem do elemento, no seu caso são 3 então ficaria `:nth-of-type(1)` `:nth-of-type(2)` `:nth-of-type(3)` uma para cada `input`

Aqui tem a documentação da Mozilla sobre essa pseudo classe.   https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Veja um exemplo prático:

```css
.form-group {
    position: relative;
}
.form-group::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.5em;
}
.form-group:nth-of-type(1)::before {
    content: "\f002";
    color: red;
}
.form-group:nth-of-type(2)::before {
    content: "\f004";
    color: blue;
}
.form-group:nth-of-type(3)::before {
    content: "\f003";
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text">
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Aqui tem uma resposta excelente entre a diferença entre `nth-of-type` e `nth-child` [Qual a diferença entre o :nth-child e o :nth-of-type?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290866/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-nth-child-e-o-nth-of-type)