# Odd e even não funcionam

Tags: css

Estou fazendo um theme no tumblr e queria alterar a cor das labels do chat, pra que em cada linha elas alternassem as cores. Acontece que todas elas ficam com a cor definida na odd

```
.label:nth-child(odd){color: #012E5E; font-style: italic;}
.label:nth-child(even){color: #D8A307; font-style: italic;}
```

Esse é o bloco do chat

```
{block:Chat}
    {block:Lines}
        {block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}<br/>
    {/block:Lines}
{/block:Chat}
```

E fica assim

[image: print da label]

Answer (score 1):

Não funciona pq cada linha sempre é `odd` no seu caso, pq cada `label` é filha única de uma Lines

Para ajustar isso vc tem que atingir a Lines, pois elas sim são irmãs umas das outras. Então seu código deveria ficar como isso:

```
.Lines:nth-child(odd) .label{color: #012E5E; font-style: italic;}
.Lines:nth-child(even) .label{color: #D8A307; font-style: italic;}
```

Snippet

```css
.Lines:nth-child(odd) .label{color: #012E5E; font-style: italic;}
.Lines:nth-child(even) .label{color: #D8A307; font-style: italic;}
```

```html
<div class="Chat">
    <div class="Lines">
        <div class="Label"><span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Lines">
        <div class="Label"><span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Lines">
        <div class="Label"><span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Lines">
        <div class="Label"><span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label} {Line}<br/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Então, o problema é que as linhas não estão dentro de uma div, então pra manipular dessa forma não traria nenhum tipo de efeito.

Comment: @lua entendi... se o seu framework funciona de forma diferente vc pode inspecionar o código já renderizado no Browser, usando a DevTools do browser para ver quis elementos ele gera, se são `<labels>` ou `<ul><li>` ou  `<dt><dd>` e adaptar seu CSS, mas o seu problema é que vc tem que usar o Odd e Even o nível acima, nos elemenetos irmãos e não nos filhos dos irmão como expliquei na resposta. Inclusive reeditei o código, da uma olhada novamente pra ver se resolve

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui, tirando o <br/> que coloquei depois do {Line} e ele funcionou, agora vou só rearranjar as linhas dentro de div para que fiquem umas embaixo das outras. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: @lua que bom que resolver, se vc acha que o problema foi resolvido considere marcar a Resposta como Aceita **✓**. Seobre o problema com o `<br>` estar quebrado a sua regra do CSS da uma olhada nessa resposta que com certeza vai te ajudar a entender o que aconteceu de fato para não ter funcionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/290866/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-o-nth-child-e-o-nth-of-type