# Comportamento da pseudo-classe :nth-child

Tags: css3, pseudo-classes

> Infelizmente a pergunta marcada como "possível duplicata" (e as suas
>   respostas) abordam outra coisa, especificamente o funcionamento da
>   variável `n` em fórmulas passadas no `:nth-child()`, o que não contempla e nem respondem às dúvidas expostas nesta pergunta.

Fiz algumas pesquisas e vi que a pseudo-classe `:nth-child()` não funciona quando usada com classes. Por exemplo:

```css
.classe:nth-child(1){
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>texto preto</div>
<div class="classe">este texto era pra ser vermelho :(</div>
<div class="classe">texto preto</div>
```

O texto do primeiro elemento da classe `.classe` não fica vermelho, como se esperaria. Porém, se eu alterar o valor do `.nth-child` para `(2)`, irá aplicar a cor vermelha ao primeiro elemento da classe (não ao segundo, como se esperaria):

```css
.classe:nth-child(2){
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>texto preto</div>
<div class="classe">este texto é vermelho, mas não deveria :/</div>
<div class="classe">este texto era pra ser vermelho :(</div>
```

Ora, se o `.nth-child()` não funciona com classes, por que quando eu altero o valor para `(2)` a propriedade é aplicada no elemento errado, e com o valor `(1)` nada acontece?

E quando eu removo a classe da segunda `div`, ao contrário do exemplo anterior, nada acontece:

```css
.classe:nth-child(2){
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>texto preto</div>
<div>texto preto</div>
<div class="classe">texto preto</div>
```

No exemplo acima, se eu alterar o valor de `(1)` para `(3)`, irá alterar a cor da última `div`, a que tem a classe `.classe`. Mas, se eu remover a classe da `div`, nada acontecerá.

Ou seja, a classe está fazendo alguma influência, só não consegui entender que influência seria essa.

A dúvida é: o estilo `.classe:nth-child()` não deveria ser ignorado pelo CSS? Qual o critério que o CSS utiliza nesses casos, já que no segundo exemplo a cor foi alterada (mesmo sendo no elemento não desejado)?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que significam o "n", números e sinais nos seletores "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/o-que-significam-o-n-n%c3%bameros-e-sinais-nos-seletores-nth-child-ou-nth-last)

Comment: o N explica especificamente o porque não funciona baseado por classes, entenderá a base dos elementos filhos/irmãos e que o comportamento do seletor é baseado nisto, a outra pergunta que complementaria a explicação é provavelmente essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290866/3635, aonde explico na resposta claramente, elementos irmãos diretos, ou seja independente de qualquer outra característica, a consideração é pelos diretos, então mesmo com o seletor de classe, o nth-**CHILD** vai avaliar todos filhos.

Comment: É basicamente o que o hugo respondeu um grupo de elementos irmãos, ou seja vai avaliar a todos irmãos na contagem no **N**-enisimo

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Antes de formular a pergunta eu li esses tópicos todos, mas pra mim elas ainda não conseguiram esclarecer as dúvidas que eu tinha. A resposta do HugoCSS foi bem específica e clara pra mim. Creio que poderá ajudar alguém leigo como eu no futuro. Valeu!

Comment: Não vejo complemento tão extra assim na resposta, ambos links que citei abordam completamente, aqui o erro cai mais para *erro de digitação/uso*, desculpe estou apenas sendo sincero sobre a abordagem técnica, se entende o funcionamento técnico entende o problema, independe ter ter exemplos ou não, a ideia é entender o CHILD da palavra, é claro que CSS é confuso a primeira vista, mas se o entendimento técnico é explorado ai sua percepção muda de angulo o que fará entender melhor o comportamento de DOM, box-model e outros seletores em geral ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento É que pra vc que já entende é mais fácil. Eu ainda tô aprendendo algumas coisas. Mas agradeço as explicações.

Comment: Mas é isso que estou explicando, se você buscar entender o comportamento técnico vai entender o porque algo falha, claro que existem as situações chamada de *"computação mistica"* que realmente mesmo tendo conhecimento técnico ainda sim as vezes não entendemos porque algo para de funcionar ou voltar a funcionar sozinho (algo comum para qualquer um que trabalha na área de TI), mas ainda sim não deves abandonar ou fugir do conhecimento técnico, entender isto é o fundamental para dominar as coisas, ao contrário disto é como se desejasse dirigir um carro antes mesmo de aprender a andar ;)

Comment: Espero que entenda toda explicação técnica e o que estou tentando lhe passar para que você evite o caminho das pedras no futuro, afinal para a maior partes das coisas existem motivos (motivos técnicos) para se comportarem de determinadas formas, feliz ano novo!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Valeu! pra vc tb!  

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regra CSS tem que ser válida para ser aplicada, ou seja, tem que haver as duas coisas para ser `true`, classe e filho.

E veja que o `nth-child` é para **um grupo de elementos irmãos**, não importa sem tem classe ou não. A classe fica apenas como um complemento a regra, pois como vc pode ver é possível selecional um elemento no grupo apenas com `:nth-child(n)` sem declarar classe o tipo de elemento.

> A pseudo-classe CSS `:nth-child()` seleciona elementos com base em suas posições em um grupo de elementos irmãos.

*Fonte na documentação da Mozilla*: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Vamos ao exemplo.

Aqui temos um grupo de 5 irmão, todos eles são `:nth-child`(1)a(5), porém para o CSS ser aplicado ele tem que ser o `:nth-child(X)` e ter a classe `.classe`, então tem que estar com as duas condições `true`. ***Deixei os comentários no código***

```css
/* vai aplicar */
.classe :nth-child(1){
  color: green;
}
/* não vai aplicar, não tem a classe */
.classe:nth-child(1){
  color: red;
}
/* vai aplicar tem a classe e é o 2 irmão */
.classe:nth-child(2){
  color: red;
}
/* não vai aplicar, pois é o 4 filho, mas sem a classe */
.classe:nth-child(4){
  color: red;
}
/* vai aplicar */
.classe:nth-child(5){
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="">irmão 1 - este texto a regra falha</div>
  <div class="classe">irmão 2 -texto deve ser vermelho</div>
  <div class="classe">irmão 3
    <div>filho 1 selecionado apenas com ":nth-child(1)" sem classe ou elemento</div>
    <div>filho 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="">irmão 4 - este texto a regra falha</div>
  <div class="classe">irmão 5 - este texto é azul :(</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Agora entendi a parada... achei que era meio complicado mas vejo que é bem simples. Ambas as condições devem atender ao seletor. :D

Comment: Estava prestes a formular tal resposta!

Comment: @Sam assumo que quando vi seus exemplos fiquei bem confuso também rss, mas ai fiquei olhando e o código ficou me olhando de volta, ai caiu a ficha! Mas foi um questionamento interessante da sua parte.

Comment: @LipESprY cheguei primeiro nessa :D

Comment: Pra vc ver que uma simples explicação clareia tudo, e o que parecia complicado se torna simples. Mas juro que fiquei meio bolado com isso, não estava conseguindo pegar a lógica. Valeu!

Comment: Vale a pena lembrar, também, que independe do tipo dos elementos. `nth-child()` vai pegar **todos os elementos filhos**. Sejam eles *`div`, `p`, `span`, etc*!

Comment: @LipESprY o que me confundia no início era essa palava "filho"... quando na verdade ele seleciona os irmãos, que na raiz seriam filhos do body, ou se dentro de um div por exemplo seriam filhos dessa div, mas irmãos entre si. Isso as vezes confunde um pouco quem não está familiarizado

Comment: Cara, vou até formular uma resposta em complemento à sua. Vai que cola...

Comment: @LipESprY sim fique a vontade, sempre é bom complementar, pois fica como um data base, mesmo se não estiver totalmente dentro do escopo da questão, vale como ponto extra rss

Comment: @Sam quando a gente enxerga todos os elementos, independente da classe, como membros de um mesmo grupo ai o nth-child começa a fazer sentido. Bom final de ano pro cê mestre! ;) []´s

Comment: pra vc tb!  

Answer (score 3):

> O seletor `nth-child(n)` corresponde a cada elemento que é o enésimo filho, independentemente do tipo, de seu pai.
>
> Fonte: [W3Schools - CSS :nth-child() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Ao utilizar tal seletor, você deve atentar-se principalmente ao **elemento pai**.

Difícil entender, mas é assim mesmo! Você cria o seletor e ele **considera todos os elementos filhos de seu pai**! (Bugou?!)

> "*- O texto do primeiro elemento da classe `.classe` não fica vermelho, como se esperaria. Porém, se eu alterar o valor do `.nth-child` para `(2)`, irá aplicar a cor vermelha ao primeiro elemento da classe (não ao segundo, como se esperaria).*" (sic)

Veja este exemplo (na pergunta):

```css
.classe:nth-child(1) {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>texto preto</div>
        <div class="classe">este texto era pra ser vermelho :(</div>
        <div class="classe">texto preto</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- `<body>` é o **elemento pai**;
- `<div>texto preto</div>` é o **elemento filho #1**. Equivalente a `:nth-child(1)`;
- `<div class="classe">este texto era pra ser vermelho :(</div>` é o **elemento filho #2**. Equivalente a `:nth-child(2)`;
- `<div class="classe">texto preto</div>` é o **elemento filho #3**. Equivalente a `:nth-child(3)`;

Acontece que para o seletor `.classe:nth-child(1)` funcionar no filho #1, ele não poderia ter mencionado a *classe-alvo*: `.classe`! Dessa forma, só vai "*bindar*" quando bater o número do elemento com a classe (Ahh, e não se esqueça do papai!).

**Outra questão**: se **consideram os filhos do pai, independente do tipo do filho**! Veja:

```html
<body>
    <div>texto preto</div>
    <p class="classe">este texto era pra ser vermelho :(</p>
    <span class="classe">texto preto</span>
    <strong>texto preto</strong>
    <i>texto preto</i>
</body>
```

- `<body>` é o **elemento pai**;
- `<div>texto preto</div>` é o **elemento filho #1**;
- `<p class="classe">este texto era pra ser vermelho :(</p>` é o **elemento filho #2**;
- `<span class="classe">texto preto</span>` é o **elemento filho #3**;
- `<strong>texto preto</strong>` é o **elemento filho #4**;
- `<i>texto preto</i>` é o **elemento filho #5**;

Esta resposta é um *complemento* da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353798/45810) do [hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl).

Comment: Boa explicação. ObG!

Comment: É isso ai mesmo. Te dou uma dica, coloque os exemplo que vc fez no Snippet, para podermos executar e ver o exemplo funcionando, isso ajuda muito a visualizar e "linkar" o output com o texto código.

Comment: @hugocsl sua dica é uma ordem! (Acho snippet desnecessário quando o objetivo não é rodar o código, mas sua opnião vale!)