# Como mudar a cor de apenas uma palavra em um parágrafo?

Tags: html, css

Por exemplo, em um parágrafo:

```
<p id="paragrafo">
    Bla bla bla
    banana uva morango
    bla bla bla
</p>
```

Como eu mudaria a cor só da palavra "uva", por exemplo?

Comment: Não pode editar o HTML pra isso?

Comment: Não sei. Posso? Como?

Comment: `<span class="cor">uva</span>`

Comment: Acho que a pergunta carece de informações. O texto é dinâmico? Vc não pode alterar direto o HTML? Por que "uva"? E se for outro texto?

Comment: Perdão, eu não sabia que tinha que informar isso. Posso alterar diretamente o HTML sim.

Comment: @Sam Ops! Verdade! kkkk! Malz! Sempre confundo vc com o [hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl)... Olha a postagem que confundi: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/353798/45810. O tiro saiu pela culatra.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Como mudar a cor de apenas uma palavra em um parágrafo?

Coloque um `span`, que é a *tag* mais recomendada para esta finalidade na palavra `uva` e estilize como quiser:

```html
<p id="paragrafo">
    Bla bla bla
    banana <span style="color: #f00;">uva</span> morango
    bla bla bla
</p>
```

Outra forma, mais ideal, seria adicionar uma classe à *tag* `span` e estilizar dentro de um bloco com *tag* `style`:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .corVermelha {
        color: #f00;
    }
</style>

<p id="paragrafo">
    Bla bla bla
    banana <span class="corVermelha">uva</span> morango
    bla bla bla
</p>
```

PS: Recomenda-se que o bloco da *tag* `style` fique dentro do bloco da *tag* `head` do *HTML*. Por mais que funcione fora, é aconselhável que faça assim.

**Referências:**

> [HTML `<span>` Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp);
>
> [HTML `<style>` Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp);

Por fim, recomendo que estude um pouco sobre as *tags* do *HTML* e sobre a estilização com *CSS*.

Comment: Obrigado, cara. Era isso mesmo. Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Coloque seu texto personalizável dentro de uma tag  e atribuía a ela uma class, desta forma você tem um elemento inline personalizável. Espero ter ajudado

```css
.palavra{
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<p id="paragrafo">
Bla bla bla
banana 
morango
bla bla bla
<span class="palavra">uva<span> 
</p>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Era exatamente o que eu precisava.

Comment: Disponha! Valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer assim

```
<p id="paragrafo">
    Bla bla bla
    banana <span style="color: #4286f4">uva</span> morango
    bla bla bla
</p>
```