# Selecionar a primeira ocorrência da classe usando css

Tags: css

Se eu tiro o primeiro paragrafo contendo a classe `.oculta` funciona, mas caso contrario o seletor `nth-child` não funciona. Tanto o `nth-child` quanto o `first-child` não funcionam por algum motivo, mesmo aparentando estar tudo certo.

> Quero pegar a primeira ocorrência de uma determinada classe.

```css
.oculta {
  display: none;
}
.mostra:first-child {
  background: brown
}
```

```html
<p class="oculta">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
<p class="mostra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
<p class="mostra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
<p class="mostra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
```

Comment: O primeiro elemento com a classe `.mostra` não é `first-child`, pois já tem um elemento antes dele, o `p.oculta`. Ou seja, o único `first-child` nesse caso é o `<p class="oculta">`.

Comment: Mas essa não seria a primeira classe? p:first-child não seria diferente de .mostra:first-child?

Comment: Conhece algum jeito de pegar a primeira ocorrência de uma determinada classe apenas com css?

Comment: Primeira classe não tem a ver com primeiro filho. O `first-child` pega o primeiro filho de alguma coisa. O primeiro `.mostra` não é primeiro filho de nenhum elemento.

Comment: Cara, com CSS eu não sei como faz isso.

Comment: @hugocsl tem como fazer isso aí?

Comment: @Sam a forma como ele perguntou acaba ficando como duplicada mesmo, mas esse questionamento no comentário muda um pouco as coisas... Estou até testando aqui, mas acredito que a forma mais fácil seria incluir uma classe a mais no primeiro elemento tipo `mostrat n1`, mas ainda estou testando.

Comment: Otavio a forma como vc pergunto deixa a pergunta como duplicada, mas te aconcelho a editar e perguntar como algo como *"Selecionar a primeira ocorrência da classe"* ou algo do tipo, ai eu removo a duplicada ok

Comment: Pronto, editei ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Não funciona pelo simples fato do .mostra não ser o primeiro filho dos parágrafos, mesmo tendo a primeira classe .mostra.

Você pode usar o nth-child e com isso decidir o background do mesmo:

```css
.oculta {
  display: none;
}
.mostra:nth-child(2) {
  background: brown
}
```

```html
<p class="oculta">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
<p class="mostra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
<p class="mostra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
<p class="mostra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus repudiandae perferendis adipisci, reprehenderit ipsam, accusantium ea nulla consequatur, quam exercitationem cumque explicabo! Officiis consectetur culpa ducimus, quo quam officia omnis?</p>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 1):

O que acontece é que o seu primeiro `child` é `.oculta`, pois ele é o primeiro filho do `body` que é o pai de todos os seus elementos. Aqui vc pode ler mais a respeito [Comportamento da pseudo-classe :nth-child](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/353794/comportamento-da-pseudo-classe-nth-child/) e vc vai perceber que na verdade não existe um `.mostrar:first-child`, por isso a classe não aplica no elemento.

Agora para selecionar a primeira ocorrência apenas com *pseudo-classes* como `:nth-chilt`, `:first-of-type` etc, vc não vai conseguir fazer de forma consistente, pois caso vc coloque algum elemento antes, vc pode acabar quebrando regras como `p:nth-child(n+3)`.

A minha dica para esse caso em específico é usar o seletor `+`, veja que com ele não importa quantos `oculta` tenham antes do `mostra`, ele só vai aplicar a classe caso tenha um `oculta` seguido de um `mostra` (`oculta + mostra`).

Deixei um comentário no código, com uma ressalva, pois sempre que acontecer um `.oculta + .mostra` no HTML a regra CSS vai aplicar....

```css
.oculta + .mostra {
 background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<p class="oculta">oculta</p>
<p class="oculta">oculta</p>
<p class="mostra">mostra</p>
<p class="mostra">mostra</p>
<p class="mostra">mostra</p>
<p class="oculta">oculta</p>
<!-- <p class="mostra">mostra</p> esse element tb vai ficar com o BG marrom caso vc o descomente, pois ele é um elemento .MOSTRA mas que tem um .OCULTA antes dele-->
```