# Alinhar itens do elemento conforme classe usando flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Tenho o seguinte menu:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #444;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <span class="item">Esquerda 1</span>
  <span class="item right">Direita 1</span>
  <span class="item">Esquerda 2</span>
  <span class="item">Esquerda 3</span>
  <span class="item right">Direita 2</span>
</div>
```

Como faço para que, usando `flexbox`, todos os elementos que possuam a classe "`right`" alinhem-se à direita mantendo os elementos sem essa classe à esquerda? Também preciso que o espaço restante fique entre todos os elementos da direita e esquerda. Assim:

[image]

PS: Não desejo criar dois *wrappers* adicionais para separar os elementos. Quero saber se é possível separá-los somente com CSS e usando a estrutura HTML mencionada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode usar a propriedade `order` nos filho de um `flex` *container*, depois só no primeiro elemento com a classe `.right` vc coloca `margin-left:auto`, ele vai "empurrar" todos os outros elementos com a classe `.right` para o final do *container*

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #444;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

.right {
  order: 2;
}
.right.primeiro {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <span class="item">Esquerda 1</span>
  <span class="item right primeiro">Direita 1</span>
  <span class="item">Esquerda 2</span>
  <span class="item">Esquerda 3</span>
  <span class="item right">Direita 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Legal, Hugo! Obrigado pela resposta. Mas existe algum jeito de chegar nisso sem adicionar a classe `primeiro`?

Comment: @LuizFelipe tem, mas para mim é pode ser gambiarra rss... vc pode criar um span vazio como último item do menu, e nele vc coloca flex-grow: 1; Se te interessa eu edito a pergunta com esse modelo

Comment: Então não precisa... O que eu realmente precisava era que fosse possível fazer sem mexer no HTML. Vou acabar ficando com a abordagem da classe `primeiro` mesmo.  Mas se você descobrir ou souber de um jeito sem mexer no HTML, ficarei feliz em saber!! :D

Comment: @LuizFelipe uma dica, talvez com diplay Grid no lugar do display Flex, seja possível fazer sem precisar do Span vazio ou da classe extra Primeiro

Comment: Ainda estou meio atrasado no CSS e não sei nada de CSS Grid. :v Quando eu for aprender darei uma olhada numa alternativa usando isso. :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe um detalhe, se vc sabe que o segundo item sempre vai ter a classe .right vc pode usar esse CSS, ai não precisa da classe .primeiro. `.item:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}`

Comment: @LuizFelipe as vezes isso pode te interessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380734/selecionar-a-primeira-ocorr%C3%AAncia-da-classe-usando-css/

Answer (score 0):

Poderia colocar `margin-left: auto` apenas no segundo elemento `.item` e `order: 1` na classe `.right`. Isso fará com que os elementos da classe `.right` se alinhem à direita fazendo com que o segundo filho `.item` tenha uma margem à esquerda automática do último elemento que só tenha a classe `.item`:

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  xflex-direction: row;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #444;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

.item:nth-child(2){
   margin-left: auto;
}

.right{
   order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <span class="item">Esquerda 1</span>
  <span class="item right">Direita 1</span>
  <span class="item">Esquerda 2</span>
  <span class="item">Esquerda 3</span>
  <span class="item right">Direita 2</span>
</div>
```