# Utilização da propriedade nth:child()

Tags: css3

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de se deixar consecutivamente as cores **AZUL**, **ROSA** e **AMARELO**, tentei utilizando **nth:child** mas não entendi muito bem como fazer, pois deixou na sequência que gostaria apenas nos 3 primeiros elementos:

```css
.grades {
    width: 550px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;       
    flex-wrap: wrap;         
    justify-content: flex-start;      
    align-items: baseline;      
}
.grade {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.grade:nth-child(1n+0) {
    background-color: #009ADE;    /*AZUL*/
}
.grade:nth-child(2n+0) {
    background-color: #EC0080;    /*ROSA*/
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+0) {
    background-color: #FFEA00;    /*AMARELO*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grades">
   <div class="grade">00h</div>
   <div class="grade">01h</div>
   <div class="grade">02h</div>
   <div class="grade">03h</div>
   <div class="grade">04h</div>
   <div class="grade">05h</div>
   <div class="grade">06h</div>
   <div class="grade">07h</div>
   <div class="grade">08h</div>
   <div class="grade">09h</div>
   <div class="grade">10h</div>
   <div class="grade">11h</div>
   <div class="grade">12h</div>
   <div class="grade">13h</div>
   <div class="grade">14h</div>
   <div class="grade">15h</div>
   <div class="grade">16h</div>
   <div class="grade">17h</div>
   <div class="grade">18h</div>
   <div class="grade">19h</div>
   <div class="grade">20h</div>
   <div class="grade">21h</div>
   <div class="grade">22h</div>
   <div class="grade">23h</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere as linhas conforme abaixo:

```
    .grade:nth-child(3n+1) {
        background-color: #009ADE;    /*AZUL*/
    }
    .grade:nth-child(3n+2) {
        background-color: #EC0080;    /*ROSA*/
    }
    .grade:nth-child(3n+3) {
        background-color: #FFEA00;    /*AMARELO*/
    }
```

no nth-chield o número antes no né um múltiplo e depois do "mais" é uma acréscimo.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

```css
.grades {
    width: 550px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;       
    flex-wrap: wrap;         
    justify-content: flex-start;      
    align-items: baseline;      
}
.grade {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
    
.grade:nth-child(3n+1) {
        background-color: #009ADE;    /*AZUL*/
    }
    .grade:nth-child(3n+2) {
        background-color: #EC0080;    /*ROSA*/
    }
    .grade:nth-child(3n+3) {
        background-color: #FFEA00;    /*AMARELO*/
    }
```

```html
<div class="grades">
   <div class="grade">00h</div>
   <div class="grade">01h</div>
   <div class="grade">02h</div>
   <div class="grade">03h</div>
   <div class="grade">04h</div>
   <div class="grade">05h</div>
   <div class="grade">06h</div>
   <div class="grade">07h</div>
   <div class="grade">08h</div>
   <div class="grade">09h</div>
   <div class="grade">10h</div>
   <div class="grade">11h</div>
   <div class="grade">12h</div>
   <div class="grade">13h</div>
   <div class="grade">14h</div>
   <div class="grade">15h</div>
   <div class="grade">16h</div>
   <div class="grade">17h</div>
   <div class="grade">18h</div>
   <div class="grade">19h</div>
   <div class="grade">20h</div>
   <div class="grade">21h</div>
   <div class="grade">22h</div>
   <div class="grade">23h</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

```
.grade:nth-child(3n+1) { /*AZUL*/ }
.grade:nth-child(3n+2) { /*ROSA*/ }
.grade:nth-child(3n+0) { /*AMARELO*/ }
```

---

A notação funcional do [`:nth-child(An + B)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Functional_notation) é mais fácil de se entender se você pensar como uma função JS (na minha opinião, é claro).

Imagine que:

```
:nth-child(An + B)
```

equivale em JS a:

```
(n % A) === B;
```

Ou seja:

- A é o valor que define a amplitude do ciclo (de quantos em quantos elementos o padrão recomeça).
- B é o valor que define em que parte dentro destes ciclos você quer aplicar o CSS.

Se a regra for `:nth-child(3n+0)` a amplitude é 3, ou seja, o padrão se repetirá a cada 3 elementos e será aplicado quando o resto de divisão for `0`. A pegadinha aqui é que o **primeiro índice é `1`**. Então um exemplo com 9 elementos ficaria:

```
// Regra: 3n+0
elemento_1 = 1 % 3 == 1 // false
elemento_2 = 2 % 3 == 2 // false
elemento_3 = 3 % 3 == 0 // true
elemento_4 = 4 % 3 == 1 // false
elemento_5 = 5 % 3 == 2 // false
elemento_6 = 6 % 3 == 0 // true
elemento_7 = 7 % 3 == 1 // false
elemento_8 = 8 % 3 == 2 // false
elemento_9 = 9 % 3 == 0 // true
```

Então se você quiser um padrão de repetição de 3 cores, na ordem Azul, Rosa e Amarelo. Basta usar as regras `:nth(3n+1)`, `:nth(3n+2)` e `:nth(3n+0)` para que todos tenham a mesma amplitude e para que cada uma delas seja aplicada a cada passo.

Teu exemplo corrigido:

```css
.grades {
    width: 550px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;       
    flex-wrap: wrap;         
    justify-content: flex-start;      
    align-items: baseline;      
}
.grade {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: #009ADE;    /*AZUL*/
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color: #EC0080;    /*ROSA*/
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+0) {
    background-color: #FFEA00;    /*AMARELO*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grades">
   <div class="grade">00h</div>
   <div class="grade">01h</div>
   <div class="grade">02h</div>
   <div class="grade">03h</div>
   <div class="grade">04h</div>
   <div class="grade">05h</div>
   <div class="grade">06h</div>
   <div class="grade">07h</div>
   <div class="grade">08h</div>
   <div class="grade">09h</div>
   <div class="grade">10h</div>
   <div class="grade">11h</div>
   <div class="grade">12h</div>
   <div class="grade">13h</div>
   <div class="grade">14h</div>
   <div class="grade">15h</div>
   <div class="grade">16h</div>
   <div class="grade">17h</div>
   <div class="grade">18h</div>
   <div class="grade">19h</div>
   <div class="grade">20h</div>
   <div class="grade">21h</div>
   <div class="grade">22h</div>
   <div class="grade">23h</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito boa explicação Fernando!

Comment: Foi o jeito que eu consegui entender essa treta. :D

Comment: Sugiro leitura do [link que eu vinculei acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/70), procurei deixar bem explicado e com demonstrações

Comment: Excelente sugestão Bacco! E parabéns pelo novo cargo. :)

Answer (score 1):

No nth-child o primeiro número corresponde ao intervalo para aplicar o estilo no próximo elemento filho, que no seu caso sempre será 3. O segundo pode ser usado para definir de onde irá começar a seleção.

Alterei o seu código de exemplo conforme abaixo:

```css
.grades {
    width: 550px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;       
    flex-wrap: wrap;         
    justify-content: flex-start;      
    align-items: baseline;      
}
.grade {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: #009ADE;    /*AZUL*/
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color: #EC0080;    /*ROSA*/
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-color: #FFEA00;    /*AMARELO*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grades">
   <div class="grade">00h</div>
   <div class="grade">01h</div>
   <div class="grade">02h</div>
   <div class="grade">03h</div>
   <div class="grade">04h</div>
   <div class="grade">05h</div>
   <div class="grade">06h</div>
   <div class="grade">07h</div>
   <div class="grade">08h</div>
   <div class="grade">09h</div>
   <div class="grade">10h</div>
   <div class="grade">11h</div>
   <div class="grade">12h</div>
   <div class="grade">13h</div>
   <div class="grade">14h</div>
   <div class="grade">15h</div>
   <div class="grade">16h</div>
   <div class="grade">17h</div>
   <div class="grade">18h</div>
   <div class="grade">19h</div>
   <div class="grade">20h</div>
   <div class="grade">21h</div>
   <div class="grade">22h</div>
   <div class="grade">23h</div>
</div>
```