# Exibir apenas os 3 primeiros elementos de uma lista (Javascript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Alguns elementos dentro que pode variar de acordo com a página. Consigo percorrer esse UL, e tratar cada LI como um elemento do Array. A minha dúvida é como é possível eu exibir apenas os 3 primeiros LI e esconder o restante para que não seja exibido.

```
<ul class="minhaClasse">
<li>Elemento</li>
<li>Elemento</li>
<li>Elemento</li>
<li>Elemento</li>
<li>Elemento</li>
</ul>
```

Meu projeto possui jQuery então se facilitar é viável tbm =) Obg galera

Answer (score 1):

Use o método **[.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)** do jQuery com o valor 3. Como o valor é de base 0, ele irá ocultar do 4º elemento (índice 3) até o último:

```js
$(".minhaClasse li").slice(3).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="minhaClasse">
   <li>Elemento</li>
   <li>Elemento</li>
   <li>Elemento</li>
   <li>Elemento</li>
   <li>Elemento</li>
   <li>Elemento</li>
   <li>Elemento</li>
</ul>
```

O método aceita 2 argumentos: início e fim. Se o segundo for omitido, irá até o fim. Os elementos não visíveis ficarão com `display: none`.

Se quiser remover de vez os elementos não visíveis, basta trocar o `.hide()` por `.remove()`:

```
$(".minhaClasse li").slice(3).remove();
```

Comment: Vou dar +1, bem simples e enxuto.

Comment: Valeu! Dei +1 tb na sua por ser funcional, embora não tanto enxuto :D

Answer (score 1):

Pode percorrer as `li` através do método [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) e dar um [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide) nos outros:

```js
$(() => {
  $("li").each(function(index) {
    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
    
    if(index > 2) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="minhaClasse">
  <li>Elemento 1</li>
  <li>Elemento 2</li>
  <li>Elemento 3</li>
  <li>Elemento 4</li>
  <li>Elemento 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara da para fazer apenas com CSS usando `:nth-child()` vc pode pegar a partir do 3 elemento e colocar `display:none` para todo mundo.

Aqui no exemplo eu coloquei apenas `color:red` do 4 ao 6, mas vc pode colocar o que quiser como `display:none` por exemplo como fiz do 7 ao 9 que nem aparecem na tela... Se tiver interesse em ver mais sobre `nth-child()` sugiro a leitura [O que significam o "n", números e sinais nos seletores "nth-child" ou "nth-last-child"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148584/o-que-significam-o-n-n%c3%bameros-e-sinais-nos-seletores-nth-child-ou-nth-last/)

```css
li:nth-child(n+4) {
    /* display: none; */
    color: red;
}
li:nth-child(n+7) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li><!-- daqui para baixo fica vermelho -->
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li><!-- daqui para baixo não aparece -->
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
</ul>
```